# Sorting a 30 element array in C

Tags: c

Im trying to do a program that sorts 30 elements of an array.Im getting an sintaxe error, i was hoping someone could help me. I think it's happening when im calling the SelectionSort function, havent written c in a while, so i guess its sintaxe. valores means values, and valoresordenados means sorted values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_max 30
void SelectionSort (int *valores[], int n)
int main(void){
    int n,j,valores[],N_max;
    n=N_max; // Defining n as the number of elements in the arrray

    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        valores[j]=30-j; //Inserting values in the array's positions
    }
    SelectionSort(int valores[n], int n); //Calling the subprogram
    printf("valoresordenados[%d]= %d",j, valores[j]);
    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
void SelectionSort (int *valores[], int *n) { //Subprogram that sorts the values of the array
    int j,z,min,aux;
    for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
        min=j;
        for(z=j+1;z<n;z++){
            if(valores[z]<valores[min])
            min=z;
        }
    }
    if(valores[j]!=valores[min]){
        aux=valores[j];
        valores[j]=valores[min];
        valores[min]=aux;

    }
}
```

Comment: `syntax` error.

Comment: `int n,j,valores[]`?

Comment: That smells like C code but it sure doesn't look like it. Please, *properly indent* your code and pick meaningful variable names so we can understand your intent.

Comment: valores means values, it is the 30 element array

Comment: @coderredoc We're being axed a question.

Comment: @tadman.: Huh..seems so.

Comment: Instead of providing a translation table for the terms used in the code, the same amount of time could have just replaced those terms in the code itself.

Comment: Please format your code so people can read it.

Comment: Try indenting your code...you would make the next developer reading your code *happy*.

Comment: its not my code, but ill try

Comment: @Alex96 that's better. Working with other people's code is not always easy, but if that code is poorly formatted it's horrible.

Comment: 'Im trying to do a program'... if it's not your code, maybe the author could help?

Comment: this second statement: `#define N_max 30
void SelectionSort (int *valores[], int n)` is missing a trailing semicolon.

Comment: generally, `#define` names are ALL CAPS with an underscore separating the major words

Comment: regarding: `int n,j,valores[],N_max;`,  1) the array size is missing for `valores[]`  2) for ease of readability, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) the `#define`d value N_max is being redeclared as a `int` variable.

Comment: strongly suggest elimination of the variable `n` as the value is already available in the `#define N_max 30`

Comment: For ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert a appropriate space: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

Comment: regarding: `   SelectionSort( int valores[n], int n); //Calling the subprogram
`  When calling a sub function, do NOT include the types of the parameters, and the parameter: `valories]n]` is passing the contents of the 'n'th entry in the array.  (which happens to be 1 beyond the end of the array, so is undefined behavior

Comment: regarding sorting an array, suggest google for `bubble sort` or `insertion sort` algorithm` or `selection sort` then implement that algorithm in your function: `SelectionSort()`

Comment: regarding: `for( j=0;j< N_max; j++ )` plus `printf("valoresordenados[%d]= %d",j, valores[j]);  The value in `j` will be `N_max`  so accessing `valores[j]` is one past the end of the array.  I.E. undefined behavior.   Note: in C, array indexes are 0...(number of elements in array -1)

Comment: in this prototype: void SelectionSort (int *valores[], int n ); the parameter valores[] is being declared as an array of pointers to integers. That is not correct, Note: in C, a reference to an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array, Suggest: void SelectionSort (int valores[], int n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that your prototype looks different to the actual function.

```
void SelectionSort (int *valores[], int n);  // u forgot ;
```

vs.

```
void SelectionSort (int *valores[], int *n)
```

which takes an address to an integer instead of an integer.

Also this

```
SelectionSort (int valores[n], int n); // Calling the subprogram
```

is not valid syntax, you need to write (and remove the * in front of n from the function prototype)

```
SelectionSort (valores, n); // Calling the subprogram
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a semi-colon ';' at line 5

```
void SelectionSort (int *valores[], int n);
```

Comment: that is just one of several problems in the code.  There are also several statements that result in undefined behavior and the sort algorithm does not work; however, this does clear up the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

There may be the problem with your function call.
It should be like :

```
SelectionSort(valores, &n);
```

This is the syntax error, I think you are getting.

Comment: why pass the address of `n`?  it is not being changed in the sub function,  Suggest: `SelectionSort( valores, n );`

Comment: void SelectionSort (int *valores[], int *n)

The syntax of the function says pass the pointer, that's why the address is passed.

Comment: there is nothing stopping the signature of the function being changed.   A good reason to change the signature is that the macro N_max is visible over the whole file so no need to pass 'n' .